# Solving for a variable when given equivalent expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving this problem:

> If x and y are positive integers and $$\sqrt{x}=y=3$$
>   then what is the value of $$y^2$$

So I thought this was simple:

$$(\sqrt{x}=y=3)^2$$
$$x=y^2=9$$
$$y^2 = 9$$

My choices are
$$A. x-9 $$
$$B. x+9$$
$$C. x-6\sqrt{x}+9$$
$$D. x^2-6\sqrt{x}+9$$

And I just plugged and checked to see which one gave me 81, give that I know:

$$x = 9$$
$$\sqrt{x} = 3$$
$$x^2 = 81$$

So after plugging in:
$$A. 9-9=0 $$
$$B. 9+9=18$$
$$C. 9-6\sqrt{9}+9=0$$
$$D. x^2-6\sqrt{x}+9=72$$

I was told the answer is C, but how could that be the answer?

Comment: As the question is written, you should be checking for a value of $y^2=9$, not $81$, but none of the choices match that either.

Comment: THIS is exactly the reason why I hate multiple choices tests. As a teacher, I mean... The OP made the right calculations to find out that the question contained a mistake. In a open written test his answer would have been a right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has a typo: it should be
$$\sqrt{x} - y = 3$$
Rearranging yields
$$y^2 = (\sqrt{x} - 3)^2 = x - 6 \sqrt{x} + 9.$$

Comment: So many of these review books have mistakes. It is ridiculous. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the given, it should be square root of $x = y+3$ to give $C$ as the answer.

Comment: Welvome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).